# How can I generate ant.d Form with multiple dynamic rows?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I'm trying to create Form using ReactJS and antd Form.
Each row in the form needs to render a different element (Input / Select) based on the user selection in the first element in the row.

See image for example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8wqK.png)

The first row works fine, the problem starts on the second row: when I change the value in "param" it changes the 3rd input element type in all the rows.

I added the code here:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/select-row-gcsfzj?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A33%2C30-33%2C35

Steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Add row
2. Select param-1 value in "param" the 3rd element in the row is now "text input"
3. Add new row
4. Select param-2 value in "param", now the 3rd element type is "Select" but also all other rows have changed, and I need to change only the current row and keep all other rows as is.

How can I fix this?

I tried to use form with Form.List with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same `selectedParam` state to handle multiple rows. So if update one `param` it will update all other rows.

Second you are not using antd List properly. When iterating over `fields` array provide by Form.List, each field/item will have a key `name` of type number. You can call it as a index of that field. Since each row has 3 fields, you can assign a key to each field so it get store in form at that particular index like this `<Form.Item name={[field.name, "param"]}>...`. Note that you do not need to add Form.List `name` before the start of `name={[field.name, "param"]}` as it's already added by antd.

Now based on each row selected param, you want to render a custom field like Input, Select.... I have created a component `DynamicField` that accepts the `name` as prop (you can say the index of that partuicular field/row...) and using `Form.useWatch`, i listen for particular Form value and render the field accordingly. Here you need to pass the complete name path.

Here's the complete code.

```
import { Button, Form, Input, Select, type SelectProps, Space } from 'antd';

type FormType = { transactionFilter: Array<{ param: string; operator: string; value: string }> };

const paramOptions: SelectProps['options'] = [
    { label: 'param-1', value: 'param-1' },
    { label: 'param-2', value: 'param-2' },
    { label: 'param-3', value: 'param-3' }
];

const operatorOptions: SelectProps['options'] = [
    { label: 'operator-1', value: 'operator-1' },
    { label: 'operator-2', value: 'operator-2' }
];

export default function App() {
    const [form] = Form.useForm<FormType>();

    const onFinish = (values: FormType) => {
        console.log('Received values of form:', values);
    };

    return (
        <Form onFinish={onFinish} className='my-form' form={form}>
            <Form.List name='transactionFilter'>
                {(fields, { add }) => (
                    <div id='second-div' style={{ display: 'flex', rowGap: 16, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        {fields.map((field) => (
                            <div key={field.key} id='3rd-div'>
                                <Space>
                                    <Form.Item label='param' name={[field.name, 'param']}>
                                        <Select style={{ width: 120 }} placeholder='params' options={paramOptions} />
                                    </Form.Item>
                                    <Form.Item label='operator' name={[field.name, 'operator']}>
                                        <Select style={{ width: 120 }} placeholder='operator' options={operatorOptions} />
                                    </Form.Item>
                                    <DynamicField name={field.name} />
                                </Space>
                            </div>
                        ))}

                        <Button onClick={() => add()}>+ Add Row</Button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </Form.List>
        </Form>
    );
}

const DynamicField = ({ name }: { name: number }) => {
    const param = Form.useWatch(['transactionFilter', name, 'param']);

    if (param === 'param-1') {
        return (
            <Form.Item label='text' name={[name, 'value']}>
                <Input placeholder='value-text-input' />
            </Form.Item>
        );
    }

    if (param === 'param-2') {
        return (
            <Form.Item label='select' name={[name, 'value']}>
                <Select
                    style={{ width: 150 }}
                    placeholder={'Select-input'}
                    options={[
                        { label: 'value-1', value: 'value-1' },
                        { label: 'value-2', value: 'value-2' }
                    ]}
                />
            </Form.Item>
        );
    }

    return null;
};
```